# Stirling numbers of first order

Tags: combinatorics

Show that the number of permutations of $n$ numbers, for $n ≥ 2$, with two cycles is at most $(n−1)!\log n$.

I know so far that from my notes that $S(n,1) = (n-1)!$ and that $S(n,2) = (n-1)!H_{n-1}$ also according to them. I assume you can make $H_{n-1}$ equal $\log n$. And also understand that $n ≥ 2$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that $H_{n-1} >\log n$: $$
H_{n - 1}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{k}}  > \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\int_k^{k + 1} {\frac{{dt}}{t}} }  = \int_1^n {\frac{{dt}}{t}}  = \log n.
$$ It is true however that $H_{n-1} <1+\log n$.

Comment: the question sorry is actually to prove ((−1)!(log(n-1)+1)

Comment: the question has been revised so do you know how to make Hn-1 = (log(n-1)+1).

Answer (score 1):

If $n\geq 2$, then
$$
H_{n - 1}  = 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 2}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{k}}  \le 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 2}^{n - 1} {\int_{k - 1}^k {\frac{{dt}}{t}} }  = 1 + \int_1^{n - 1} {\frac{{dt}}{t}}  = 1 + \log (n - 1).
$$

Comment: how do I give you a thumbs up

Comment: very helpful thank you